# How to stop python recursion on met condition

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make a function to return the FIRST sum_list that summates to n. I've written a function that returns all sum_lists but it only works for some inputs. The prototype must remain the same. The code is below:

```
def find_sum(n, i, p_list, sum_list):
    if n == 0:
        print(sum_list)
        return True
    elif n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        for index in range(len(p_list)):
            sum_list.append(p_list[index])
            find_sum(n-p_list[index], i, p_list, sum_list)
            sum_list.pop()
```

The input that outputs every sum_list is below:

```
find_sum(146, 0, [17, 29, 37], [])
```

The input that causes errors is:

```
find_sum(262, 0, [3, 5, 7], [])
```

I don't understand why the recursion doesn't end the first time the sum_list is printed when the following code is executed.

```
if n == 0:
    print(sum_list)
    return
```

Please let me know if my code or logic is wrong, and point me in the correct direction. This is my first recursive function and I'm still not confident I understand the concept.

Comment: `return` doesn't cause the entire string of recursive calls to end. Like with any other function, all it does is cause *that specific call* to end and return control to the function that called it (which happens to be the same function here). Recursion works just like any other function call.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for your comment. I know that return ends the specific return, I just don't understand why it continues recursion if, when the print condition is met, the for loop doesn't get executed?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking why the `for` loops continues once `n==0` happens in one of the recursive calls?

Comment: Because in your `for` loop you iterate over the indexs (3 in this case) and call the function for each one, but then each function call starts that again. So you end up with a big mess of append/pops.

Comment: @BloodSexMagik Okay, I understand that. The condition is met, so it returns to the for loop, but then pops the last element from the "working" sum_list, rendering the solution useless. How can I properly prevent that? Is there some way I can prevent the sum_list.pop() for a successful sum_list?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve? If you explain it clearly I will try and help.

Comment: @BloodSexMagik Given an integer, n, and a list of prime numbers, p_list, return sum_list, which contains a combination of numbers from p_list that adds up to n. The issue Im running in to, is that once I print a successful sum_list, the sum_list.pop() is run and the sum_list is incorrect, making the for loop run again and again. (I think). Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am just trying to learn recursion and re-learn python). I only need the first successful p_list to be printed.

Comment: I would use a while loop for this and a `while n>0:`. Then use `break` statements as needed. However I think your maths logic is a bit off, but I'm not an expert as I can't see how the logic in the lower `for` loop would ever yield the answer you're after.

Comment: @BloodSexMagik I understand where you're coming from. Im just practicing recursion and want to solve this problem with recursion.